# if I delete a document in cloud firestore but it is as documentReference in other documents, is it deleted from these automatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with cloud firestore and I think it's deleting references to a document when I delete that document and I don't understand why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit help center, take tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I delete a document in cloud firestore but it is as documentReference in other documents, is it deleted from these automatically?

If you have a document that has a property that holds a `DocumentReference` that points to a document that is deleted, the reference still remains. In order to have a clean database and consistent data, when you delete a document, you should also delete all the references that point to that particular (deleted) document.

Note, that this is not happening automatically, you should write code your self to achieve that.